# JS - Is there a memory/performance difference between an external function to modify objects, compared to an internal function?

Tags: javascript, performance, javascript-objects

Say I'm creating lots of objects in the following way:

```
function Bird() {
    this.prop1 = 1;
    this.prop2 = 2;

    ...
}

const bird1 = new Bird();
const bird2 = new Bird();
```

Is it more memory- or resource-intensive to have the same function nested within every `Bird` object, compared to a single external function?

Internal:

```
function Bird() {
    this.prop1 = 1;
    this.prop2 = 2;

    this.modFunc = function() {
        this.prop1 = this.prop1 * 10;
    }
}

const bird = new Bird();

bird.modFunc();
```

External:

```
function Bird() {
    this.prop1 = 1;
    this.prop2 = 2;
}

function modFunc(b) {
    b.prop1 = b.prop1 * 10;
}

const bird = new Bird();

modFunc(bird);
```

This is purely educational for myself. I'm not (currently) dealing with anything where I have so many objects that this makes any sort of difference. But if there were many millions or more objects, would one have an advantage over the other?

To me, the latter seems more efficient, with the external function. Because with the internal version, I could do something like:

```
bird.modFunc = function() {...};
```

and rewrite the internal function. So each object must therefor have its own internal reference to its own internal function. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a small memory difference. With an internal function, every `Bird` instance will have a `modFunc` property that points to the function. With an external function, there's just one global variable containing that function.

Also, each of these properties will refer to a distinct function. It might be possible for the compiler to arrange for them to share code, but there will still be memory overhead for the function headers.

The normal way to add this function would be to define it on the prototype, not a global variable:

```
Bird.prototype.modFunc = function() {
    this.prop1 = this.prop1 * 10;
}

bird = new Bird();
bird.modFunc();
```

This has the same memory overhead as the global variable, but it doesn't affect the global namespace. It has a small time expense, because looking up the function name requires following the prototype chain. But I think most JavaScript engines will optimize this in the JIT compiler, since prototype functions are at the heart of OOP in JS.

Comment: "*I'm not sure why this is*" - simply because the function is defined in the constructor, which evaluates to a new function object every time.

Comment: @Bergi But the compiler should theoretically be able to tell that every invocation of the constructor returns the same function, because there's no scope dependancy, and stash that function somewhere to reuse it each time.

Comment: Thanks for your test and thoughts! Is it better practice to use `Bird.prototype.modFunc = ...`, opposed to defining the function within the constructor?

Comment: Yes, using prototype functions is generally considered better in an OO application.

Comment: In ES6 you would implement all this using `class`.

Comment: @Barmar The spec is clear on a function expression evaluating to a new function object every time, and mandates that `bird1.modFunc !== bird2.modFunc`. A JS implementation cannot decide to do this in any other way. Of course, all of those function objects do share the same compiled code.

Comment: Thanks. I've changed my answer to say that there will be distinct function object, but they might share code.